# Automating cursor movements, mouse clicks and keyboard inputs in not helping to show that user is present on system

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a software installed on my system which basically peeks my activity during working hours. It send a report saying how much time i was away from my system etc.

Since i m .net c# developer hence trying to break this system through my programming skills.

I have basically written up a windows form application which opens up an notepad for me and start typing some random characters into it. simultaneously it also performs some random clicks and moves the mouse cursor to give a feel that some one is on system and working even when i am not :)

I also use "SetThreadExecutionState" Pinvoke calls to keep system awake.I have also observed the User idle time and last interactivity time through "GetLastInputInfo" PInvoke system call while my mouse/keyboard are in automation process and it is also fine.

But this is not working for me. It works perfectly till 5 mins and then somehow it detects that user is not present on system.

any suggestions for the same.

Comment: This is not solvable by anyone, apart from the creators of the activity program. It totally depends on how the application is implemented. For all we know it uses a USB dongle in between your mouse and PC, looks at which applications are active and perhaps the way you invoke those mouse moves are detected too.

Comment: @CodeCaster thats why i bring the notepad application in foreground(make it active) through PInvoke and then send random keyboard inputs to type. Can you suggest some more methods so that i can give a try and it might work.

Comment: You missed my point. Nobody knows how the application works except the ones who built it. I don't like guess games. Ask them.

Comment: Just set the PC to receive automatic security patches to the O/S. It will always seem busy. :-)

Comment: I suspect you'll need to beef-up your programming skills to learn how to write driver filters.  Which you cannot do in C#.  Surely a spy program like this listens to real keyboard and mouse driver notifications.

Answer (score 2):

Get a decompiler, crack-open the spying application and see how it is working inside. Only knowing the internal workings, you can create a "workable" any-spying program. But I would not bother with emulation of the activity, but rather spoof the way it reports to the server.

However, depending on where you live, it might be illegal to do these things and I would not recommend cheating your employer. And if spying gets on your nerves I'd also suggest to brush up your CV and start searching for a new job.

Comment: Thanks for reply @trailmax. I have already de-compiled the application but the code base is huge. So just seeking out help if any. Any ways thanks will definitely try to break it asap :)